# What does 'idle tale' mean?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jest

> later the term denoted an idle tale

What does it mean? Any references would be welcome.

While researching 'idle' I found this https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/idle 
 except it doesn't seem to me to fit perfectly in the phrase above thus I'm asking.

It seems like maybe it's something like a story that is presented as true but is not actually true, but that's just a wild guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An *idle tale* is another way of saying "**utter nonsense**". This phrase usually gives you a hint to the beliefs of the person stating the phrase more than anything.

For example: Imagine a hard-line atheist talking to a hard-line believer on matters of faith

An atheist might conclude that the story of creation is an "idle tale"

The believer might conclude that an atheist's explanation of the big bang is an "idle tale"